# How to count business days from a given date in SQL Server using a calendar reference table

Tags: sql-server, date, count, calendar

I have two tables. One table is a Calendar that has a `date` column and a `kindofday` column.  The `kindofday` column contains 'bankday', 'saturday', 'sunday' and 'holiday'.  I need to account for holidays otherwise there are several queries on the net that would work...

```
        date                          kindofday
1999-08-24 00:00:00:000                bankday
```

I'm struggling to build a query that can count the number of working days from a given date.  Something like:

`Select [date] +  12 business days`.  I am not sure how to use the Calendar table as a reference for this - essentially I need to find a date in this calendar table then count down the column a number of business days and extract that date.  I'll be putting this in a function so no worries about complexity. There is probably a stupid simple solution that I am just not seeing.

I'm open to any solutions that take holidays into consideration even if they do not use my calendar table. I can alter the calendar table however I need to in order to make this work... ie: using `binary` instead of `string` 'bankday' etc...

I have tried this: I have removed all the non bankdays from the calendar and added an `integer` key, and then `set @date = (select key from calendar where @date=[date]` and then added the amount of business days to that key and returned the date but the issue was when `@date` was a non bankday it wouldn't find a match in the calendar table...

Comment: Just a side note, it seems your `date` column has type of `datetime`. Storing dates as timestamps is asking for trouble.

Comment: @nord, yes I do conversions in the query to remove the timestamps

Comment: It does not have to be in DB in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reword the question to "Of the next `@count` bankdays after `@start_date`, which one occurs last?"

```
SELECT @end_date = MAX(date)
FROM (
  SELECT TOP(@count)
    date
  FROM Calendar
  WHERE date > @start_date
    AND kindofday = 'bankday'
  ORDER BY date
) t
```

Comment: VERY SLICK BRO!  I see what you did there...  and might I say VERY SLICK!  and it works like a charm... put it in function form and ran smoothly!  Kudos for use of the TOP function... that is where my small mind needed help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SQL Server, you can use a [ranking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) function to order the non-banking days and get a sequence number, and then match it with the number of days you wish to add.

```
SELECT date
FROM (
  SELECT date AS DATE, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS PLUS_DAYS
  FROM calendar
  WHERE date > @start_date AND KINDOFDAY <> 'bankday'
  ORDER BY date
) TEMP 
WHERE TEMP.PLUS_DAYS = @plus_days
```

Comment: It should be KINDOFDAY = 'bankday'  but this will also break down if there are less than @plus_days in the Calendar Table.  E.g. you looking for + 12 days but only + 10 days exist in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this older question and got curious about answering with window functions to eliminate the nested query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@count)
    @end_date = MAX(date) OVER ()
FROM
    Calendar
WHERE
    date > @start_date
    AND kindofday = 'bankday'
```

And the reality is because `MAX(date) OVER()` will be the same for every row you don't even need the `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT TOP (@count)
    @end_date = MAX(date) OVER ()
FROM
    Calendar
WHERE
    date > @start_date
    AND kindofday = 'bankday'
```

Here is an entire example for you:

```
DECLARE @end_date AS DATETIME
DECLARE @start_date AS DATETIME = '12/15/2016'
DECLARE @count INT = 12

;WITH Calendar AS (
    SELECT
       CAST('12/1/2016' AS DATETIME) as date
           ,'bankday' as kindofday
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       date + 1
       ,CASE
          WHEN date + 1 = '12/25/2016' THEN 'holiday'
          WHEN DATEPART(dw,date + 1) IN (1,7) THEN 'weekend'
          ELSE 'bankday'
       END
    FROM
       Calendar
    WHERE date + 1 <= EOMONTH(date)
)

SELECT TOP (@count)
    @end_date = MAX(date) OVER ()
FROM
    Calendar
WHERE
    date > @start_date
    AND kindofday = 'bankday'

SELECT @end_date
```